# Filter XMLs in a folder based on node value using xslt (MatLab)

Tags: xml, matlab, xslt

I have a folder containing thousands of xml entries (and this will be updated every day) and what i want to do is to filter all these entries based on a specific node value. e.g.

**Filename1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<addresses>
   <address>
      <type>A</type> 
      <name>Joe</name>
      <street>Baker street 5</street>
   </address>
</addresses>
```

and **Filename2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<addresses>
   <address>
      <type>B</type> 
      <name>Mary</name>
      <street>Baker street 5</street>
   </address>
</addresses>
```

Is it possible with XSLT to filter and to take in a folder only entries which contain:

```
<type>A</type>
```

If i do this with MatLab xlst function

```
 XmlStr = xslt (filename,  xslstyle, '-tostring');
```

i would expect that the output should be a string if

type == A else empty string.

What i have done

**xlsstyle.xsl** -- **UPDATED**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>  
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:if test="//type[(node()='A')]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>         
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but this returns for filename1.xml (correct)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<addresses>

  <address>

    <type>A</type> 

     <name>Joe</name>

    <street>Baker street 5</street>

 </address>

</addresses>
```

and for the filename2.xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So i will show how I have done it which may helps in the future other "foxes" (who wants to do it through MatLab - because indeed there are many ways).

using the above xsl file

```
 function FilterXML(xslstyle)
 % Author: amigo
 % Date:   10/08/2014
 % Description: Filter xml files based on node value using XSLT
 %
 %INPUTS
 %
 % xslstyle     string of the xslstyle file e.g 'xslstyle.xsl'
 %
 %% Import some java classes that we need
 import org.xml.sax.InputSource
 import javax.xml.parsers.*
 import java.io.*

 %% Make list of all *xml files in our dir
 filename=dir('*.xml');

 %% Make folder where we will write the output
 if ~exist('output','dir')
   mkdir output
 end

% this is just the pattern that i want to avoid
x = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';

%% Main
 for i=1:length(filename)
   XmlStr = xslt (filename(i).name,  xslstyle, '-tostring');
   if strcmp(XmlStr,x)
      continue
   else
      iS = InputSource();
      iS.setCharacterStream(StringReader(XmlStr));
      XmlObj = xmlread(iS);
      out = ['output',filesep,filename(i).name];
      xmlwrite(out,XmlObj);
  end
end
end
```

Any other idea will be very welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

Not having matlab at hand, I used the cli tool "xsltproc" (based on libexml & libxslt from http://www.xmlsoft.org) to reproduce the transformation.

```
xsltproc -load-trace -noout -v -debug xslstyle.xsl Filename*.xml > xsldebug.log 2>&1
```

The stylesheet processes as intended, Filename2.xml is skipped properly when leaving "-noout" unset. It seems the MatLab.xslt() function creates one output file per input file. Maybe there is a parameter / configuration switch to change that behavior.